# Problem with crash reporter

Tags: 18.04, crash, ubuntu-mate, seamonkey

I am having frequent problems with Crash Reporter showing up whenever I use Seamonkey.

I have tried re-installing it as well as using a new profile.

It is so frustrating.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Going to bing.com is causing the crashes. Can someone verify that happens with their use of Seamonkey? It does not happen with Firefox.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Ubuntu MATE 18.04.6 LTS with Seamonkey (seamonkey-mozilla-build 2.53.10-0ubuntu1) using Intel iGPU. Have you tried to restart SeaMonkey in Safe Mode?

Comment: Look in `/var/crash/`. Read the crash fiiles (they are simple text files) to begin your diagnostic process.

Comment: @waltinator That file had nothing to help.

Comment: @N0rbert Restarting in Safe Mode eliminates the crash. So, what does that tell me?

Comment: You have to check list of installed Addons. Visit Tools → Addons Manager and try to disable some of them.